# When an angularjs project is minified and bundled how can start the application by adding as a component to third party webpage

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular project minified and bundled called build.js which has all the partial html files converted to js by $templatecache and other dev dependencies as dev-dep.js now if I need to load this as component in a third party website can I use the ng-app to load.

Suppose the angularjs minified project file is called build.js and added into a webpage using  then how can call the application in div container to work as a component

Answer (score 0):

You will be have to release it as a component / module that the third party website may be able to load.  I am assuming that the third party website is also an Angular JS website.

Comment: No third party website has nothing to do with Angular and it works on PHP magento platform.So my angularjs application is added as a js file into the page using <script src> tag.I know in Angular2.0 we can make a component and add it as a directive element

Answer (score 0):

The third-party website will have to load your AngularJS bundle (as well as Angular itself, and any dependencies your bundle has that are not bundled with it). It will also need to add `ng-app="myBundledModule"` to an element in the DOM that is higher up than any elements you intend to affect with your module.

Assuming you have your module bundled with all of its dependencies in a single file, and the third-party app is adding the `ng-app` directive high enough in the DOM (to the `html` or `body` tag, let's say), there is still one more thing: The directives provided by your module will need to be used somewhere in the DOM.

For a truly self-contained app that is easy to add to any website, you'll probably want to inject some elements into the DOM when your app bootstraps itself. You can use `angular.element(body).append('<my-directive></my-directive>')`, or something along those lines, to impart new functionality onto the site.